# What is the best tutorial or method to model a head?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, motion-capture

There used to be a really good tutorial on creating a human head model (Natalie Portman) on Youtube. It’s gone now.

I want to model my own head to then add rigging and lip sync. All the ones I’ve found now on YouTube aren’t as good as the Natalie Portman one I found.

Can anyone recommend another tutorial (video or site) that can help me achieve my goal of animating myself?

Thanks. I’m stlll a total noob!

Comment: I think a great exercice is to recreate this topology again and again until you can do it without any model because it's the basic face topology: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/3X/9/d/9dad3a45d9d09d03c97f441a33a5a868df5e9033.jpg

Comment: I do like the simplicity of it. Is there a guided tutorial you know of that uses this topology as its method?

Comment: you should look at "low-poly head blender" in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=low-poly+head+blender   and also, as I said, try to reproduce this head topology again and again   ;)

Comment: I believe theses were the videos you were looking for.
https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenderella/56040ecf044a2a00a515ada6

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this dude [*Alimayo Arango*](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_47ItRT9U4nnElhSK8JcmQ) out he has a lot of (Hyper-Detailed) character modeling tutorials (including other stuff!)

P.S His models/designs are Not *AAA* but i think they're enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

After trying countless times what worked for me is a tutorial from Carlos R. Bisquertt:
http://www.cgarena.com/freestuff/tutorials/misc/headmodeling/index.html

He also created a nice ear modeling tutorial...